# django countries encoding is not giving correct name

Tags: python, django, python-unicode, django-countries

I am using `django_countries` module for countries list, the problem is there are couple of countries with special characters like `'Åland Islands'` and `'Saint Barthélemy'`.

I am calling this method to get the country name:

```
country_label = fields.Country(form.cleaned_data.get('country')[0:2]).name
```

I know that country_label is lazy translated proxy object of django utils, but it is not giving the right name rather it gives `'Ã…land Islands'`. any suggestions for this please?

Answer (score 3):

Django stores `unicode` string using code points and identifies the string as unicode for further processing. 
UTF-8 uses four 8-bit bytes encoding, so the `unicode` string that's being used by Django needs to be decoded or interpreted from code point notation to its UTF-8 notation at some point. 
In the case of Åland Islands, what seems to be happening is that it's taking the UTF-8 byte encoding and interpret it as code points to convert the string.

The string django_countries returns is most likely `u'\xc5land Islands'` where `\xc5` is the UTF code point notation of Å. In UTF-8 byte notation `\xc5` becomes `\xc3\x85` where each number `\xc3` and `\x85` is a 8-bit byte. See:
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=xc5&mode=hex

Or you can use country_label = fields.Country(form.cleaned_data.get('country')[0:2]).name.encode('utf-8') to go from `u'\xc5land Islands'` to `'\xc3\x85land Islands'`

If you take then each byte and use them as code points, you'll see it'll give you these characters: `Ã…`
See: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=xc3&mode=hex
And: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=x85&mode=hex

See code snippet with html notation of these characters.

```html
<div id="test">&#xC3;&#x85;&#xC5;</div>
```

So I'm guessing you have 2 different encodings in you application. One way to get from `u'\xc5land Islands'` to `u'\xc3\x85land Islands'` would be to in an utf-8 environment encode to UTF-8 which would convert `u'\xc5'` to `'\xc3\x85'` and then decode to `unicode` from `iso-8859` which would give `u'\xc3\x85land Islands'`. But since it's not in the code you're providing, I'm guessing it's happening somewhere between the moment you set `country_label` and the moment your output isn't displayed properly. Either automatically because of encodings settings, or through an explicit assignation somewhere.

**FIRST EDIT**:

To set encoding for you app, add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your py file and `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in  of your template. 
And to get unicode string from a django.utils.functional.**proxy** object you can call `unicode()`. Like this:

```
country_label = unicode(fields.Country(form.cleaned_data.get('country')[0:2]).name)
```

**SECOND EDIT**:

One other way to figure out where the problem is would be to use `force_bytes` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding) Like this:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
country_label = fields.Country(form.cleaned_data.get('country')[0:2]).name
forced_country_label = force_bytes(country_label, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict')
```

But since you already tried many conversions without success, maybe the problem is more complex. Can you share your version of `django_countries`, `Python` and your django app language settings? 
What you can do also is go see directly in your `djano_countries` package (that should be in your python directory), find the file data.py and open it to see what it looks like. Maybe the data itself is corrupted.

Comment: I used `country_label = fields.Country(form.cleaned_data.get('country')[0:2]).name.encode('utf-8')` in the code but still it rendered as `Ã…land`. I am using render method to get the template.

Comment: See edit, I'm supposing country_label goes straight to the context and isn't saved in db before being rendered?

Comment: @mad_programmer What happens if you pass encoding argument to `unicode()`, like this: `unicode(fields.Country(...).name, 'UTF-8')`?

Comment: @xyres Your solution gives error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, __proxy__ found`

Comment: @JulienGrégoire no the solution you suggested doesnt work, it still gives the same string. Yes, it goes to context through render method and I use it directly in template. Not getting stored anywhere in db.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals #Place as first import.
```

AND / OR

```
country_label = fields.Country(form.cleaned_data.get('country')[0:2]).name.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Comment: both the solutions dont work. The second one gives exception. In the second option I get `UnicodeDecodeError

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
`

Answer (score 0):

Just this this week I encountered a similar encoding error. I believe the problem is because the machine encoding is differ with the one on Python. Try to add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then, open up a new terminal and run the Django app again.